# Inequality of $|\sin(a+b)-\sin(c+d)|<|(a+b)-(c+d)|$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I am reading a solution with this inequality:
$$|\sin(a+b)-\sin(c+d)|\le|(a+b)-(c+d)|$$

The solution just says this holds, but I don't quite understand how?

I am also trying to know if it can be generalized, like to solve other trig inequality such as
$$|\cos(a+b)-\cos(c+d)|\le\text{what combination of $(a+b)$ and $(c+d)$}$$

Comment: Hint: the mean value theorem.

Comment: Simplifying hint: maybe consider $\sin x - \sin y.$

Comment: got it, thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, you can simplify the problem by considering $x = a+b,\ y = c+d$. So what we want to prove is that $|\sin x - \sin y| \le |x - y|$.

You can use the mean value theorem: fix $x, y \in \mathbb R$. If they are equal, the result is obvious, so  suppose WLOG $x > y$. Since $f$ is differentiable, $\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = f'(z_0) = \cos(z_0)$ for some $z_0 \in (x, y)$. Taking the absolute value on both sides and using that $|\cos(z_0)| \le 1$, you get that $|\sin x - \sin y| \le |x - y|$. Plug in your $x= a+b$ and $y = c+d$ and you're good to go.

Comment: You are overcomplicating it. Or, perish the thought, ghostwriting it.

Comment: How is this overcomplicating it? What do you mean by ghostwriting?

Comment: @gist076923 The answer is fine now. My comment was referring to the [first revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4662575/1) posted, which was completely rewritten since.